# How do I import Excel data using dynamic path created/Input on Access Form

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

In MS Access, I created a form with Form Name "Form" and created a Text Box named "Path".

When I enter a path in form with "c:Desktop.....xlsx". I should be able to import data from Excel to Access.

I tried using the Macro version in Access using the below code, but I encounter an error.

```
Function Import()
    On Error GoTo Import_Err
    Dim Str As String
        Str = Forms!Form!Path.Caption
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "EM", Str, True, ""
    Import_Exit:
        Exit Function
    Import_Err:
        MsgBox Error$
        Resume Import_Exit
End Function
```

> Error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

As I plan to give the file to others to run, they will have a different path, so we need to prefix it in their system. So instead if we have form path, then users can input the path in form and run it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet

Comment: *Consider* naming your form with a more descriptive name than `Form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```vb
Str = Forms!Form.Path
```

I would (in your shoes) use the File Open Dialog instead letting users type the file with path:

```vb
        Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        Dim FileChosen As Integer
        FileChosen = FD.show
        FD.Title = "Choose workbook"
        FD.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList    
        FD.Filters.Clear
        FD.Filters.add "Excel workbooks", "*.xlsx"
        FD.Filters.add "All files", "*.*"
        FD.FilterIndex = 1
        FD.ButtonName = "Choose this file"
        If FileChosen <> -1 Then
        'didn't choose anything (clicked on CANCEL)
            MsgBox "No file opened", vbCritical
            GoTo Exit_Function
        Else
            fileNamePath = FD.SelectedItems(1)
        End If
        Set FD = Nothing
```

and after that

```vb
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "EM", fileNamePath , True
```

Comment: HI, I did the changes as per above suggestions. Renamed form to Frmpath and text box path to txtPath. used the Str = Forms!FrmPath.txtPath. yes it do work only when I provide path in Form in box txtPath and Click ENTER button. it doesn't take without clicking "Enter" button. 
After providing path,if I don't click Enter button then it is taking previous entered path. How to take new path entered without clicking Enter button. 
based on property mentioned in above suggestion "Note that you can only get and set Text when the control has the focus". How do I Fix this Text control Focus.

Comment: HI All, Thank you. Got it. My mistake was... after entering the path still the cursor was   in same text box, it was like system was thinking still i am going to enter any other details. i was dynamically changing it and thinking it will reflect the chnages in Macro. Thank you all for your suggestions. this really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The Access [**Textbox**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox) control doesn't have a **Caption** property. But it does have two other properties:

- [**Text** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.text)
- [**Value** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.value).

AFAICT, **Text** returns the text currently in the textbox, while **Value** returns the last persisted value. If the user has modified the text in the textbox but the focus is still in the texbox, **Text** will return the user-entered new value, but **Value** will return the value before the user started editing.

Note that you can only get and set **Text** when the control has the focus.